# Ordering and grouping in mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want groups of person which is ordered by age

I tried something like this

```
Person.only(:name).asc(:age).group
```

But didn't ordered by age.

How can I do it?

I'm using mongoid beta 19.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, once you have called

```
Person.only(:name)
```

Mongoid basically considers the collection to only have that field so once you have tried to sort by age, there is no age field to sort by so it does nothing.

Try

```
Person.asc(:age).only(:name).group
```

Or possibily

```
Person.asc(:age).only([:name, :age]).group
```

Comment: To make sure I tried `Person.asc(:created_at).only(:name).group` and `Person.desc(:created_at).only(:name).group` but both giving the same results. Is am I missing any thing else or `created_at` field cannot be sorted in mongoid. I konw `Date/DateTime` is weakest part of mongodb. Is the problem was due to that?

Comment: Works well for me, thanks!
`Search.asc(:created_at).where(user_id: "5130abdfc9f2672059000005").each { |d| p d.created_at}
Fri, 01 Mar 2013 18:21:51 UTC +00:00
Fri, 01 Mar 2013 18:38:55 UTC +00:00`